# Input fields get (readonly) after hit submit button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, smarty

I have a script which is coded in PHP and smarty and I want to make some changes in this script like in user profile setting when a user click on profile setting and fill the profile data like (full name , email , bank account number , bank name , branch code , tile etc) after fill this information and click the save button the script save all setting but I want to make some of form input fields (readonly) after user submitted his/her data I want make this data (readonly) (bank name , account number , branch code , title) I mean about readonly that after user fill this and save it in profile its show to user (readonly) user can't change it only I can change it from database .

Below is the form code

```
<form id="settingsform" onsubmit="return submitform(this.id);">
<input type="hidden" name="a" value="submit" />
Bank Name:
                    </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="bank" id="bank" value="{$user_info.bank}"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td align="right" width="50%">
                    Bank Account Number:
                    </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="baccount" id="baccount" value="{$user_info.baccount}"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td align="right" width="50%">
                    Bank Account Title:
                    </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="btitle" id="btitle" value="{$user_info.btitle}"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right" width="50%">
                    Bank Branch Code:
                    </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="bcode" id="bcode" value="{$user_info.bcode}"></td>
                </tr>
<input type="submit" name="btn" value="{$lang.txt.send}" class="orange" />
```

also i am already trying like this below

```
<script>
function hide(){
  document.getElementById("bank").disabled = true;
  document.getElementById("baccount").disabled = true;
  document.getElementById("btitle").disabled = true;
  document.getElementById("bcode").disabled = true;
}
</script>
```

and

```
<input type="button" onClick="hide()" value="save">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="text" name="country" value="Norway" readonly>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_readonly.asp

Then simply do a check if the POST/GET is set for the field you want to have readonly on ->

```
<input type="text" name="country" value="Norway" <?php isset($_POST['country']) ? echo 'readonly' : ''; ?> >
```

**UPDATE**

```
<input type="text" name="country" value="Norway" <?php isset($user_info.bank) ? echo 'readonly' : ''; ?> >
```

Just replace the variable inside of the isset() with the variable of the field, depending on how you initialize the variables you might need to use

> empty()

instead, to do so just simply replace isset() with !empty()

*The reason for the ! sign is to tell the code to execute the first bit (the echo part) if the variable ISN'T empty*

**UPDATE 2**

```
<input type="text" name="country" value="Norway" {if isset($user_info.bank) } readonly {/if} >
```

Above code should work with smarty how ever, the idea is simple, simply have a "if" sentence that checks whether the variable is set/have data, and if it does, then echo 'readonly' in the input field

Comment: i have updated my question please take a look and suggest me regarding this .

Comment: So, just so make sure I understand what you want, once the user has submitted / saved his data, you want those certain fields to be readonly permanently for that user? @ShopSupport

Comment: brother is your code work with smarty template file ?

Comment: Should be, I gave it a quick go for smarty but the code should be easy to translate over to smarty @ShopSupport

Comment: brother i have tried your update2 but it still did not work . its save the value of field (bank) to database and also show it in form but did not put it (readyonly) . i mean user can edit it

Comment: Try the update 2 again @ShopSupport I changed it a bit

Comment: it also did not work . after put this code my page show white blank page .

Comment: I updated it again, I'm not use to smarty so bare with the syntax errors, the one I updated to now SHOULD work. @ShopSupport

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr) in `submitform()` like,

```
function submitform(id){
   ....
   ....
   $('#bank,#baccount').attr('readonly','readonly');
   return false;
}
```

Updated,

```
function hide(){
     $("#bank,#baccount,#btitle,#bcode").prop('disabled', true);
}
```

Or try,

```
function hide(){
     $("#bank,#baccount,#btitle,#bcode").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
}
```

Comment: can take a look at my code that i have already tried but still its not work for me .

Comment: i have tried your both updated code but still its did not work . its show empty input fields in profile setting form and also did not send any data to database . its same happening same with my code . i have already tried it with create .js file but still same .